# How does one use the component prop with custom components?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to use the Link component (from react-router) with my customized button component.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

```
<Button component={Link} to="/">
"This works"
</Button>

<CustomButton component={Link} to="/">
"And this doesn't"
</CustomButton>
```

CustomButton is a simple withStyles - component:

```
const CustomButton = withStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
    root: {
        marginLeft: '0.5rem'
        /* ...etc ... */
    },
}))((props: ButtonProps) => <Button color="default" {...props} variant="contained" />);

export default CustomButton;
```

I'm getting a type error:

> Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick, "button">, "children" | "ref" | "form" | "slot" | ...

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-borg-bqize

*It does work per se*, but the type error from the linter doesn't let me compile it (without suppressing the linter)

Comment: Apparently it just doesn't work. If someone else runs into this problem, read [this issue on github](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15827)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
const CustomButton = withStyles({
  root: {
    marginLeft: '0.5rem'
  }
})(Button);
```